# Http request issue to Ethereum network

Tags: javascript, ethereum

Currently trying to post some data into an ethereum network through axios post method in javascript, but I am currently getting the error below:

```
dispatchXhrRequest @ xhr.js:177
xhrAdapter @ xhr.js:13
dispatchRequest @ dispatchRequest.js:52
Promise.then (async)
request @ Axios.js:61
wrap @ bind.js:9
(anonymous) @ index.js:18
index.js:27 Error: Request failed with status code 400
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at settle (settle.js:17)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:62)
```

As for my code,

```
const server = "http://localhost:4030";
const axios = require('axios');


console.log(document.getElementById("search"))

document.getElementById("search").addEventListener('click', () => {

  //Obtain BlockID value from front end
  const BlockId = document.getElementById("blockID").value;

  console.log(BlockId);
  //Incorporates both transaction parameters and a signature in the body request
  //A request body is data sent by the client to your API
  //In this case, we want to send over the BlockID

axios({
  method: 'post',
  url: "https://kovan.infura.io/v3/025faa826802466c8c568db0baa4aa32",
  data: {
    blockID: BlockId
  }
}).then((response)=>{
  console.log(response);
},(error) => {
  console.log(error);
});

});
```

I believe the issue is most likely complaining because of the type I am posting to the url. However, I'm not quite sure what is wrong with the type submission - any advice will be highly appreciated!

Comment: Infura acts as a node provider - not as a REST API, so you need to structure the request differently... What is your intention? To get  block data for the `blockId`?

Comment: Yes, my intention is to get the block data for the block ID. The code above is my front end, and I want to be able to enter a block number and send it to the backend where it will retrieve information regarding this block ID.